# Non Responsive Page

Tags: html, css

I'm running Facebook Ads for one of my clients, however, his website is quite old and there are a few pages that aren't being responsive in mobile version. I know basic HTML & CSS, enough to do simple coding but am not sure where to start with this issue.

Issue: The linked pages are below with images attached. In mobile version the main content div is basically only taking up three quarters of the screen. The rest of the client's pages are fine (occupy the whole screen) when on mobile.

http://stkildafitnesstrainer.com.au/our-trainers.html
http://stkildafitnesstrainer.com.au/services.html

Thanks for your help

[image]
[image]

Comment: so are you saying you *want* them to be responsive, they just aren't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

Seeing the comments below, and as I was too young to care about disabilities. I'm sorry, this is the new answer:

---

Simple, add this in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

`initial-scale`, as the name says, define which scale your website will be rendered.

**There is also other parameters to the `content` tag:**

`width=device-width` sets the `<body>` width to be the same of the device, just like `height=device-height` is the same for height.

`user-scalable=no`, this says you are not able to zoom the page **AND IT'S NOT RECOMMENDED**, you can also set this parameter to `yes`.

Comment: help to be helped! :D

Comment: Oh, Sorry @soulshined

Comment: so do you propose anything else @soulshined by any chance?

Comment: *"and it's common when you are building a page"* nothing could be more wrong. See a discussion [here about its relevancy](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/80487/revisiting-user-scalable-no) Is it needed for some functionality (like say, google maps) maybe. But just to use it to hack a solution together is not user friendly on any account, especially accessability. You should stay on the right track and focus on responsive design so all users can benefit @Justin

Comment: Really sorry, im new here